# How to purchase a used Apple Watch?

Tags: hardware, apple-watch

What necessary and sufficient steps can one take, from the software side of the device, when (s)he is purchasing a used Apple Watch, to make sure the Watch is what the seller is claiming it to be?

Are the steps different for GPS and GPS + Cellular models?

---

I have never used an Apple Watch before. Would just syncing up the Watch my iTunes be a necessary and sufficient way to ascertain if the Watch is ok to purchase?

Comment: How would this be any different from purchasing a new Apple Watch?

Comment: @Allan: The motivation behind the question is a friend of mine who got conned into purchasing a locked iPhone, and my ignorance of Apple’s Watches. If the answer to this question is - “A AW can be purchased without worries from anyone.”, then that’s good to know.

Comment: *A AW can be purchased without worries from anyone.*  Unless you're buying it from a reputable dealer/reseller that gives you some level of buyer protection, **nobody** can make that statement.   Buying second hand outside of traditional purchasing avenues has inherent risks.  If being conned will be substantially damaging to you/your friend, (IMO) it's not worth the risk; spend the extra $$$ and get it from a legitimate seller.

Comment: @Allan: That's why the question - _What necessary and sufficient steps can one take, when (s)he is purchasing a used Apple Watch, to make sure the Watch is what the seller is claiming it to be?_

Comment: If I told you an Apple Watch was "hardly used" but in fact been dissembled and is now no longer water resistant, there's absolutely nothing you can do to know/see this.  You would be conned.  There are no steps.

Comment: @Allan like buying a Landrover - the advert said “only used at weekends” : didn’t say for racing.... :)

Comment: @SolarMike - that sums it up in one nice clean line!

Comment: @Allan yup caveat emptor ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the software side, all one needs to do is:

1. [Update your iPhone to latest iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204);
2. [Reset the Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204568) (You can do that from Watch itself);
3. [Setup the Apple Watch using your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204505).

Once it is paired to your iPhone, it is safe to assume that the device is off the previous owner.